# Display Message To View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to display a message to my view from my controller but its doesn't happen anything. I am using ViewBag.Message to display the message. I dont know if i'm making a mistake in my code or this is not properly way to do it. This is my code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id_IngresoM,Id_Componente,Lote,Serie,Cantidad,Id_Usuario")] IngresoMateriales ingresoMateriales)
    {
        var user = "1ef69472-1b7d-460d-a6f9-9d458c5e314e";
        string msj = "";
        try
        {
            var affectedRows = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("IngresoMaterialesInspeccion @IdComponente, @Lote, @Serie, @Cantidad, @IdUsuario",
                                         new SqlParameter("@IdComponente", ingresoMateriales.Id_Componente),
                                         new SqlParameter("@Lote", ingresoMateriales.Lote),
                                         new SqlParameter("@Serie", ingresoMateriales.Serie),
                                         new SqlParameter("@Cantidad", ingresoMateriales.Cantidad),
                                         new SqlParameter("@IdUsuario", user));

            //ModelState.AddModelError("", "El Certificado no esta Vigente");
            if (affectedRows == '3')
            {
                msj = "El Certificado no esta Vigente";
            }
            else if (affectedRows == '2')
            {
                msj = "El Componente esta libre de Inspeccion";
            }
            else if (affectedRows == '1')
            {
                msj = "Componente Sospechoso";
            }
            else
            {
                msj = "Pues nada";
            }
            ViewBag.Message = msj;
            return RedirectToAction("Create");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            foreach (SqlError Error in ex.Errors)
            {
                return new JavaScriptResult { Script = Error.ToString() };
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Message = msj;   ------------------------------
        return View();  
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Serie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Serie" name="Serie" onkeypress="FunctionS(event)" />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Serie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            alert("@ViewBag.Message");   ---------------------
        };
        </script>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: There is no point assigning a value to `ViewBag.Message` if you then redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` will send a 302 response to the browser with the new url in the location header and the browser will make a totally new GET request to get that page. Remember **Http is stateless**. Your second request has no idea what happened int he previous request.

ViewBag does not work in this scenario. ViewBag works only if you are returning to the same view. Razor view will be able to read the view bag items because it was set during the same request.

If you want to persist data between your current request and next request, you may consider using TempData.

You can set TempData in the action method of first request.

```
TempData["Message"] = "Some message in Request 1";
return RedirectToAction("Create");
```

and in the next request(`Create`), you can read it like

```
@if (TempData["Message"] != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            alert("@(TempData["Message"] as string)"); 
        };
    </script>
}
```

TempData's lifetime is short. the TempData dictionary item will be cleared at the end of the second request. That means, If you hit F5 (refresh), you will not see the alert again !

Another option is to send the message in the querystring while redirecting. You can do it like

```
return RedirectToAction("Create",new { msg="SomeMessageGoesViaQueryString");
```

This will add a querystring item(msg) when it does the redirect. You can add a parameter named `msg` to the Create action and read this value and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: `TempData` is cleared at the end of the next response - not "once read".

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thanks for catching that. Fixed in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
return View(ingresoMateriales);
```

Because you are already in the "post" Create method, it will send you back to the same view and you will not lose the data you typed for the model,

Another issue is the exceptions, it is not recommended to send sql/backend system error messages to the end user, better use it for logging and during development.